# How can I save multiple models in Laravel by using only one database Query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to update every row of my table associated with the model MyModel. Each update requires PHP code to be executed. In my case it is not a problem, but I wondered how to do this more efficiently?

```
MyModel::chunk(1000, function (Collection $collection) {
     foreach ($collection as $model) {
         $pascalCaseModelName = $model->modelName;
         $myModel->modelAlias = Str::snake($pascalCaseModelName);
         $myModel->save();
     }
});
```

Right now I save each model after I processed it. That means a database query is executed for every model. I wonder if it is possible to save a whole chunk with on statement that triggers one database query instead.

The only solution I could find is the saveMany method. But this can only be applied to relations.

Comment: Option A would be to use SQL functions directly, like in this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670745/change-the-values-in-a-column-from-pascalcase-to-snake-case-using-sql, otherwise, it depends on how often you're running this. If it's just once, i.e. to "backfill" missing data that will now be added when creating/updating records, don't worry about performance too much; it's a data migration at that point.

Comment: @TimLewis yes it is just to "backfill" the missing data and performance is not a problem. I was just curious if Laravel provided functions for this.

Comment: @Timo I woud just do `$collection->each()` instead of `MyModel::chunk(1000,)`. The collection can already go over each record, no need to chunk

Comment: Gotcha. Laravel methods tend to focus on a single Model, and `save()` executes an `UPDATE` query for that specific row via `UPDATE ... WHERE id = ...`. You could try to chunk the updates and perform them all in a single statement (or multiple; IIRC there's a limit). But again, this is all really only a factor if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Zacharias's suggestion, I managed to solve the problem. But I
used the upsert method instead of update.

```php
MyModel::chunk(1000, function (Collection $collection) {
    $updates = [];
    
    foreach ($collection as $model) {
        $pascalCaseModelName = $model->modelName;
        $updates[] = [
            'id' => $model->id,
            'model_alias' => Str::snake($pascalCaseModelName),
        ];
    }

    DB::table('my_models')->upsert(
        $updates,
        ['id'], 
        ['model_alias']
    );
});
```

While update can update multiple records, it can't insert different values for each model. upsert can. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#upserts

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering how does this works? $updates[] = [
        'id' => $model->id,
        'model_alias' => Str::snake($pascalCaseModelName),
     ];

won't the $updates variable's value be replaced in every iteration?  or is it just the same as array_push()?

Comment: @YusufGiovanno Yes, it's the same like array_push. $updates[] = ... is the shorthand to append elements to an array in PHP.

Comment: Now that’s new to me, thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
MyModel::chunk(1000, function (Collection $collection) {
     $updates = [];

     foreach ($collection as $model) {
         $pascalCaseModelName = $model->modelName;
         $updates[] = [
            'id' => $model->id,
            'model_alias' => Str::snake($pascalCaseModelName),
         ];
     }

     if (!empty($updates)) {
         DB::table('my_models')->update($updates, 'id');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Great idea! Look at my own answer, I used the upsert method to make the code work.